# Modem to Router to Router = slow internet?

Tags: networking, router, lan, modem

Having a little problem here. I've got a configuration of a Modem (A) that's connected (by the WAN-port) to another router (B) and this one connectects to a another router (C) (LAN to WAN). It actually all works, used to work better though.

Since I've resetted the configuration of the router C, both routers allow only very slow internet use. Before that it was all fine.

I'm not 100% sure whether I set up router C correct again, but it's weird anyway that router B is now slow too. Only connecting to the modem itself gives me the full internet speed. There's no QoS enabled anywhere though. 
Anyone got suggestions what I could do here ? I'm pretty baffed about it.

Comment: Try Connecting A to C and A to B. Then see if both B and C are slow. Or just one of them.  What about if you go to just test if it's DNS.. So try browsing to http://209.85.229.103 (google) and do some searches compared to www.google.com

Comment: Tried connecting A to C and it worked...to restore the old setup though I just switched B and C and had no problems anymore (for what reason howsoever)...was a good idea, thanks a lot !!!

Comment: Don't stop there. You should isolate the problem a bit more, and save yourself from future troubles,  Try A to B, no C. See if that is slow.  From a strictly troubleshooting perspective, Something may be dodgy, one of your routers, or your modem, or some conflict betwen 2 items,maybe not just an issue with A-B-C Some of these items wil liv on and you should label dodgy setups or items with a note so you know for next time.OR could label them all and say itemx-itemy-itemz is slow.But more troubleshooting tests might get a sharper diagnosis which saves you more trouble in future

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The connection will be as fast as your slowest router. If you notice that http speed is way slower than https go check if there is some packet inspection activated.